# Facebook Like Button + Open Graph + Website = Pushing Updates to Likes?

Tags: facebook-like, push-notification

I'm looking for a solution for a client, in which they have a page with 27k likes from a Like button installed on a microsite (instead of a Facebook page). They'd like to push an update out to those 27k people. Based off previous knowledge and documentation (noted below), this *should* be possible.

In the [Facebook Developer page for the Like button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/), it states the following:

> If you include Open Graph tags on your Web page, your page becomes **equivalent** to a Facebook page. This means when a user clicks a Like button on your page, a **connection** is made between your page and the user. Your page will appear in the "Likes and Interests" section of the user's profile, **and you have the ability to publish updates to the user**.

[Emphasis is mine.]

However, it doesn't actually explain how you can actually publish updates to the user in this type of connection. I've searched here on SO and elsewhere, but nobody seems to know the answer.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

How to publish updates to users who have liked your Open Graph page is described here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/#publishing